# Set the value from the div into a hidden input when IMAGE is dropped

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, dom, hidden-field

I want t insert the ID of the dropped image into a hidden input when its dropped in the div.
**This is the HTML**

```
<td> 
   <div id="rang1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div> 
   <input type="hidden" value="" id="rang1input" name="rang1value">
</td>
```

--

```
<td> <?php echo "<img class='DraggedItem' id='".$row["IDPictogram"]."' src='data:image/jpeg;base64,".base64_encode($row['Pictogram'])."' width='90' height='90' draggable='true' ondragstart='drag(event)'>" ?> </td>
```

**This is the JS:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function allowDrop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
    }

    function drag(ev) {
        ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
    }
    $(".DraggedItem").draggable({
            helper:'clone', 
            cursor:'move'
    });

    function drop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
        $('#rang1input').val($('#rang1').html());

        var elem = document.getElementById("rang1input");
        var div = document.getElementById("rang1");
        elem.value = div.value;
        alert(elem);
    }
```

What is wrong with my code? I tried to get the ID in different ways and none of them worked.
I even tried them separated but no results either.
Can you help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQuery UI's droppable object has a **[drop event](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-drop)** with a callback that receives the event and ui object as parameters.  `ui.draggable` is an **array** that contains the object that was dragged and dropped. So, to get the id of the current draggable, you can use: `ui.draggable[0].id`.

```js
$(".DraggedItem").draggable({
  cursor: 'move'
});
$("#rang1").droppable({
  drop: function (event, ui) {
    var elemid = ui.draggable[0].id;
    $("#rang1input").val(elemid);
    alert("dropped item has id: " + elemid);
  }
});
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font: bold 25px/150% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #555;
    text-align: center;
}
#rang1 {
    background-color: #ccc;
    height: 100px;
}
input {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 34px;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    margin: 15px 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"> </script>
<img class="DraggedItem" id="1" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-90-90-8.jpg" width="90" height="90" />
<img class="DraggedItem" id="2" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-90-90-7.jpg" width="90" height="90" />
<img class="DraggedItem" id="3" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-90-90-6.jpg" width="90" height="90" />
<img class="DraggedItem" id="4" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-90-90-3.jpg" width="90" height="90" />
<div id="rang1">Drop Here</div>
<input value="" id="rang1input" name="rang1value" />
```

Comment: I just woke up to test your code and it doesn't work with me. Maybe I'm too sleepy...
Anyway thank you very much for your help, I'll try it again once I wake up.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to use the jquery ui framework with the use of $().draggable();

here is a solution using jquery ui

```js
$(function(){

    $(".DraggedItem").draggable({
            helper:'original', 
            cursor:'move',
            revert: true
    });

    $('#rang1').droppable({
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $('#rang1input').val($(ui.draggable).attr('id'));
        var imgsrc = ui.helper[0].src;
        var $img = $('<img></img>');
        $img.attr('src', imgsrc);

        $('#rang1').append($img);
      }
    });
});
```

```css
#rang1 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;  
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"> </script>
<table>
<tr>
<td> 
   <div id="rang1"></div> 
   <input type="hidden" value="" id="rang1input" name="rang1value">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> <img class='DraggedItem' id="testid" src='http://placehold.it/300x50.gif'></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Sir thank you very much for your help, I'll try the code now and tell you what the results are.
But the point is that the image stays in the div.
And I have a question: If I submit the form, will the value be in the hidden input?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean "the point is the image stays in the div"? You want to drop the image to not be cloned when it is dragged but rather move the original? That's just an option in the draggable (helper: 'original'). I'll update,  please see [the docs](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#visual-feedback) for further information.

Comment: I mean a clone will be taken from the original picture and when you drop it in the div, it remains in the div.
This is about making a scheme and the user has to see the pictures in the div. The value and id of the image is backend (something for me to program further)

Comment: There is no mention of that requirement in your post, the droppable drop event handler is passed a ui argument that has a reference to the 'helper' (the element being dragged) you can use this to create the dropped element. I have updated this example once more with this solution, but please accept this answer and if you have further requirements, try to solve them via the docs and open new questions specific to that requirement if you have trouble.